# Excluding "some" duplicate rows in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

-- Any suggestions for getting this to work in MS SQL Server 2008?

-- My definition of a 'duplicate row' is "the first 3 fields match"
-- I need to exclude the duplicates from my results, but I decide which 1 row to keep
-- Keep the rows that have a value in the 4th column (there will only be 1 row for each set of duplicate pairs)

-- The results will keep row 2 (but not row 1)
-- Also keep row 3 (but not row 4)
-- Also keep all the remaining rows (none are duplicates)
-- 8 of the 10 rows should be returned

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL)       DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    aKey Int            IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,    
    
    f1 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,  -- 1
    f2 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,  -- 2
    f3 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,  -- 3 
    f4 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    f5 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
    f6 VarChar(10)          NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0
)

INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('A', 'B', 'C', '' , 'del', '1') -- 1st of the duplicate
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'keep', '1') -- 2nd of the duplicate

INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'keep', '2') -- 1st of the duplicate
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('D', 'E', 'F', '' , 'del', '2') -- 2nd of the duplicate

INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('H', 'G', 'N', 'Q', '1', 'K')  
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('I', 'G', 'C', '' , '2', 'L')  
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('J', 'H', 'D', 'R', '3', 'P')  
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('K', 'G', 'C', '' , '4', 'K')  
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('L', 'G', 'C', 'S', '5', 'V')  
INSERT INTO #tmp(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6)    VALUES('K', 'M', 'C', '' , '6', 'K')
```

--SELECT * FROM #tmp

```
-- This "almost" works, but is excluding too many non-duplicate rows:

SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM #tmp AS t1
INNER JOIN #tmp AS t2
ON t1.f1 = t2.f1 AND t1.f2 = t2.f2 AND t1.f3 = t2.f3
WHERE t1.f4 <> ''
```

Comment: and what happens if you have two records with values in column 4 but the 3 columsn before match?  in essence you want to use `row_number() over (partition by  f1,f2,f3, f4 desc)` and return row 1 only  This assigns a row number to ech "Like" duplicate and then only returns the  1st row. but given your condition of only return those with a value in f4... there's too much vagueness in determining which record to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, excellent job posting sample data in a format that people can use. Bravo!!!! That makes it easy for people to help. Secondly, even though your stated explanation was not entirely clear you did provide enough details in the sample data to make it clear what you need to accomplish. xQbert was spot on that using ROW_NUMBER is a great way to solve this.

I used a cte here to provide some clarity in how this works. You could do that as a subquery just as easily if you desire.

```
with SortedValues as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by f1, f2, f3 order by f4 desc)
    from #tmp
)

select *
from SortedValues
where RowNum = 1
order by aKey
```

Comment: Perhaps best to also explain that empty strings `''` and `NULL` get sorted before anything else (or after if the sort is `DESC` which it is here)

Comment: Excellent point @Charlieface.

Comment: I found the "nested method" easier to understand.  But when I tried the "with/as/over/partition" method (1st time I've ever worked with it)... it worked just as well.   Bravo!  And bonus, I can now use "with/as/over/partition" in future projects, since it's really not that hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with your existing approach, instead of joining just use `exists`

```
select * 
from t
where not exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t.f1=t2.f1 
        and t.f2=t2.f2 
        and t.f3=t2.f3 
        and t.f4 =''
        and t2.akey !=t.akey
    )
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be as efficient as a row-numbering approach

Comment: This will have more *logical* reads against the table, the row number will require sorting rows; Testing on the real-world data will obviously show which is best

Comment: Not necessarily the case: an `exists` may get transformed into a sort-merge join anyway And the final `order by` in @SeanLange 's query is not actually necessary. I'll admit your solution is probably faster if there are a very significant percent of rows are duplicates, but that is unusal. Agreed one needs to test on real-world data

Comment: @Charlieface actually without the final order by there would be no way to determine the order of the rows in the output. If the order doesn't matter than yes you are correct.